# GLFW3 error: 'glfwGetWin32Window' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, windows, glfw

I was looking for a native API access in [GLFW3 documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__native.html#gafe5079aa79038b0079fc09d5f0a8e667) to get `HWND` but it's not in my `GLFW/glfw3.h` file. Is there any `#define`'s to be able to find it by compiler? I can't also find it manually in the file itself using `text-finder`, so how can I get it?

PS. I can't tag `glfw3`.

**Edit:**

Code:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU

#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WGL
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32
#include <GL/GLFW/glfw3native.h>
#include <GL/GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
...

int main()
{
    //glfw setup
    ...
    //bla bla bla
    ...
    //all I want to do is to call this one
    ScreenToClient( glfwGetWin32Window(window), &point);
}
```

Comment: Tried to include `glfw3native.h`?

Comment: @thokra Oh thanks man, but how to know which "context API" I am using?

Comment: EDIT: Scratch that, what you mean with *context API*?

Comment: @thokra I already did this `#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WGL` and 
`#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32` but still say `no context API specified`. I define it before including the header file.

Comment: @thokra Uhm, I don't know what else does that mean. It's the compiler complaining.

Comment: Did you `#define` the macros *before* including the header, like stated in the doc?

Comment: @thokra Yes, and I also try including first the `glfw3.h` before `glfw3native.h` and all sorts I can think of.

Comment: Can you post some code and the actual errors the compiler spits out?

Comment: @thokra Please see update. I don't know what to include more in my code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After getting confused by your problems I tried it my self and I think the **include order** is your problem. A minimal code example that mimics on Linux what you try to do on Windows compiles and works as intended:

```
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_X11
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_GLX
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  glfwInit();    
  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (256, 256, "GLFW", nullptr, nullptr);    
  glfwGetX11Window(window);      
  glfwTerminate();

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Added the incovation of `glfwTerminate()` for proper clean-up. Please note, of course there should be appropriate error checking taking place, but for the purpose of demonstrating a minimal example, the above is sufficient.